# Blackberry emails dated when arrive at device

Tags: blackberry, bes

We have about 200 Blackberries.  A number of users like to use Auto On/Off to turn their Blackberries off overnight so the new email notifications don't wake them up.

They are complaining that when they come back on in the morning, all the emails are timestamped with the time that the email arrived at the Blackberry (ie the "Auto On" time), rather than the timestamp that the email has in "Outlook" (ie in Exchange).

There has to be a setting somewhere on the Blackberry or in BES, but I can't find it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We recently had a BES installed and had the telecomms vendor in to assist and provide training and he just said this is how it is. You have to remember this is not windows mobile with activesync reading a copy of the mailbox. This is a reconciliation process whereby messages are directed to the device before they even hit the mailbox. Therefore the time shown is always going to be the time the device received them.

Annoying indeed at first but people quickly get used to it. I guess if you think about it its the equivalent of having your mailserver turned off over night and then all the mails arriving when you turn it on, at which point that would be the timestamp.

I would be very interested to know if there is a way around this, but i suspect it involves not turning of the BB :)

Edit: Of course the mail is shown in the order it arrived at the mailbox and if you open a mail item on the BB it will show the date it arrived at the mailbox, in the header.

Answer (score 0):

As people have previously mentioned this is a blackberry 'niggle' I have spoken to RIM about it and there isn't a way round it. Has mail gets delivered the to device before your exchange server. So if the device is asleep as far as its concerned it gets delivered when it wakes up.

Answer (score 0):

What the users could do to get around this is to set the blackberry profile to Quiet or Off - that way the messages are still delivered but they don't get disturbed by the ringing/buzzing at night.

Comment: To which the user replied "yeah, but that means I have to remember to turn it "on" again in the morning."

Answer (score -1):

I have no special insider knowledge here, but I suspect that this may be because Blackberry is a forwarding service.  Email doesn't go direct from your servers to the BB, but rather via RIM's server as an inbetween step: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry

> The software monitors the user's local "inbox", and when a new message comes in, it picks up the message and passes it to RIM's Network Operations Center (NOC). The messages are then relayed to the user's wireless provider, which in turn delivers them to the user's BlackBerry device.

What your users are likely seeing is the timestamp that the email was forwarded from RIM.

Comment: I would agree this is the case for the Internet services (i.e., regular consumers).  But wouldn't the case be different for the Enterprise crowd?  I would think that for BES customers their corporate email isn't being sent out over the wire to RIM servers and then back.  Would be a big security risk...  But I don't have knowledge of BES, so I'm hoping someone can clarify.

Comment: It is the case, I'm afraid.  Unfortunately with the Ubiquity and "oooh shiny toy" appeal of BBs, management pressure and rank-pulling so often takes precedence over good common sense.

Comment: With BES, the email is fully encrypted from BES to Device.